# How to show references for each chapter, under IEEE style?

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran, ieee-style

The standard way to include references with IEEE style is the follows:

> \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
>
> \bibliography{05_Bibliography/ref}

However, this method only shows a "Reference" section at the end of the file. I want to add a reference section for the current chapter, without a page break  between the text and refs.

Comment: Which template do you use?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You state that you use the `ieeetr` bibliography style (which is *really, really old*, by the way), which works with BibTeX, yet you've set `biblatex` as one of the tags. Now, `biblatex` and `ieeetr` are mutually incompatible. Please clarify your intended document setup.

Comment: @Mico, thank you, I didn't know 'ieeetr' and 'biblatex' are incompatible. I just wanted to use my citations according to the IEEE style. Is there a more updated/recommended way to achieve IEEE style?

Comment: Since your current approach is incompatible with `biblatex` I have removed that tag for now. It might be possible to use `biblatex` and `biblatex-ieee` to get IEEE-like bibliographies (and even chapter-wise bibliographies), but that is not the official IEEE style, nor is it compatible with all IEEE-document classes. It would greatly help if you could tell us more about your document, in particular which document class you use. Please expand the code shown so far to a so-called MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).